# Add Join query string parametrs to Resource

Tags: react-admin

I'm using React-Admin with "ra-data-treeql" (I'm using "php-crud-api").

I set
`const dataProvider = treeqlProvider('https://www.apiurl.xyz/');`

and then

`const App = () => ( <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}> <Resource name="sellers"list={sellerList} /> </Admin>`

With a "simple" resource from API all works fine but I need to join different tables (for example the partial URL in postman is sellers?join=brands&join=products).
How can I add the join parameters in Resource name? If I use
<Resource name="sellers?join=brands&join=products"list={sellerList} />
I receive an error.

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

From what i'm seeing here the error is by sending "join" two times in the query string : one time equal products and second time equal brands which confuses the api call.
But actually I wouldn't like to send this as partial path to another component.

So i would prefer to send only parameters to Resource component and there should everything operated (e.g: making query string).

```
function getQueryString(params: any, targetPath?: string) {
  if (!params) { return ''; }
  const esc = encodeURIComponent;
  const pathTo = targetPath || '';
  return `${pathTo}?${Object.keys(params)
    .filter((param) => params[param] !== null && params[param] !== undefined)
    .map((param) => `${esc(param)}=${esc(params[param])}`).join('&')}`;
}
```

Then you can call it where you want like this :

```
const qs = getQueryString({
    join: "brands",
    products: "anything",
    thirdParameter: "test"
  }, "seller");
// qs will be : "seller?join=brands&products=anything&thirdParameter=test" 
 
    const url = `your-api-base-url/${qs}`;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I followed the guide from official link (https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api#joins). Use 2 times the "join" parameter is useful to make 2 different joins. I'm interested to have this kind of response. I now will try your solution.